# Android: Navigation drawer select item different position 0

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I he created a Navigation Drawer but I don´t know how default select option 3 and the text is set to bold the Drawer when the app starts. I tried `mDrawerList.setItemChecked(2, true);` loading the Drawer but option 1 is always selected. This is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void cargarDrawerLayout(Bundle b) {

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    textosMenuLateral = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    iconosMenuLateral1 = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconos_menu_lateral1);

    iconosMenuLateral2 = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconos_menu_lateral2);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    int[] colores = {0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0};
    mDrawerList.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colores));
    mDrawerList.setDividerHeight(4);

    navDrawerItems1 = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems1.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[0], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems1.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[1], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems1.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[2], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems1.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[3], iconosMenuLateral1.getResourceId(3, -1)));

    navDrawerItems2 = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems2.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[0], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems2.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[1], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems2.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[2], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems2.add(new NavDrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[3], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(3, -1)));

    iconosMenuLateral1.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems1,
            perfilObj.getColor());
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, 
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.boton_drawerlayout, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (b == null) {
        opcionesPanelLateral(0);
    }

}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems2.get(position).getIcon());    

        opcionesPanelLateral(position);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
//      case R.id.action_settings:
//          return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

//      boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
//      menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void opcionesPanelLateral(int position) {

    Intent i;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            OficinasTurismo oficinas = new OficinasTurismo(this, 
                    R.layout.oficinas_alerta,
                    monumento);
            oficinas.show();
            break;
        case 2:
            i = new Intent(this, BusTuristico.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 3:
            ElegirPlanos planos = new ElegirPlanos(this, 
                    R.layout.elegir_plano, 
                    R.string.planosMetroRenfe, 
                    R.id.botonPlanoMetro,
                    R.id.botonPlanoRenfe); 
            planos.show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

//      if (fragment != null) {
//          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
//          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                  .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        if (position == 0) {
            setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        } else {
            setTitle(textosMenuLateral[position]);
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
//      } else {
//          // error in creating fragment
//          Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
//      }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this method

```
if (b == null) {
    opcionesPanelLateral(0);
}
```

to

```
if (b == null) {
    opcionesPanelLateral(2);
}
```

you can pass any option here for default selection

Comment: I cant change the position of nav drawer,what i am checking is,if internet is there it has to go that activity or this like that i am doing.so while internet is not there.its going to other activity.but its not changing the position and title also.  case 5:
   if (haveNetworkConnection(getBaseContext()))
            {
    System.out.println("Intenet is working"); fragment = new GinfyAdvertisementActivity();
 break;
            }
   else
   {
    Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Advertisment Page will be in Online only ", 1000).show();
displayView(6);
fragment = new Settings();break;}